# FreeMarker using javax.json.JsonObject as Data Model

Tags: freemarker

I am testing FreeMarker

**Maven** dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.json</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
        <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.23</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Simple class **User**:

```
public class User {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;

    public User(String firstName, String lastName, String email) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

}
```

Simple FreeMarker file (**basicJson.ftl**):

```
Name: ${user.firstName} ${user.lastName}
```

Class for create a **Configuration**:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import freemarker.template.Configuration;
import freemarker.template.TemplateExceptionHandler;

public class FreemarkerConfigurationFactory {

    public static Configuration newFreemarkerConfiguration() throws IOException {
        Configuration cfg = new Configuration(Configuration.VERSION_2_3_23);
        cfg.setDirectoryForTemplateLoading(new File("./templates/tests/"));
        cfg.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        cfg.setTemplateExceptionHandler(TemplateExceptionHandler.RETHROW_HANDLER);
        cfg.setLogTemplateExceptions(false);
        return cfg;
    }

}
```

**Test** class:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.json.Json;
import javax.json.JsonObject;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

import freemarker.template.Configuration;
import freemarker.template.Template;

public class FreemarkerJsonTest {

    private Configuration cfg;
    private ByteArrayOutputStream output;
    private Template template;
    private Writer writer;
    private Map<String, Object> map;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        cfg =  FreemarkerConfigurationFactory.newFreemarkerConfiguration();
        output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        writer = new OutputStreamWriter(output);
        map = new HashMap<>();
    }

    @Test
    public void objectTest() throws Exception {
        User user = new User("Clarice", "Leman", "clarice.leman@domain.com");
        map.put("user", user);
        String outputString = process("basicJson.ftl", map);
        assertEquals("Name: Clarice Leman", outputString);
    }

    @Test
    public void jsonTest() throws Exception {
        JsonObject jsonUser = Json.createObjectBuilder()
            .add("id", 10)
            .add("firstName", "Clarice")
            .add("lastName", "Leman")
            .add("email", "clarice.leman@domain.com")
            .build();

        map.put("user", jsonUser);
        String outputString = process("basicJson.ftl", map);
        assertEquals("Name: Clarice Leman", outputString);
    }

    private String process(String templateName, Object root) throws Exception {
        template = cfg.getTemplate(templateName);
        template.process(root, writer);
        return output.toString();
    }

}
```

The question is that the test "objectTest()" passes but the test "jsonTest()" no, because it produces a String:

```
Name: "Clarice" "Leman"
```

Using a Online FreeMarker Template (http://freemarker-online.kenshoo.com/):

**Template:**

```
Name: ${user.firstName} ${user.lastName}
```

**Data Model:**

```
user = {"firstName":"Clarice","lastName":"Leman","email":"clarice.leman@domain.com"}
```

**Result**

```
Name: Clarice Leman
```

Answer (score 3):

The JSON you enter on FreeMarker Online is transformed to `List`-s and `Map`-s by FreeMarker Online before passed to FreeMarker itself. The syntax of that whole box is specific to that online service. So if you have JSON to show, either it has to be converted to a something that the default `ObjectWrapper` of FreeMarker already understands, or the `ObjectWrapper` has to be extended to understand `javax.json` classes. (But often, you bind the JSON to some application-specific classes anyway, and those often already use JavaBeans conventions and `List`-s, which the default `ObjectWrapper` understands.)

Comment: Hi @ddekany, thanks for the answer.I'd think that FreeMarker already deal with javax.json classes because the output show the values as expected except that String values are quoted.

Comment: You are certainly seeing the `toString()` return value of those objects. The default `ObjectWrapper` of FreeMarker will wrap objects that it doesn't understand so that they can be used as strings, and the string value is calculated by calling `toString()`.